# Unusuable windows pops up using Shift + 2 in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04

So.. when I try to do Shift+2, I get the pop-up shown in the image. Happens using keyboard config of English (US), but not when using English (UK), then I get a "-symbol as expected. However, when performing the combination to produce a @-symbol, I get the same 'pop-up'-screen as with the English (US) config.

Anyone knows why this happens and what it is?

[image]

EDIT:
Using `gnome-control-center keyboard` to find the keymapping for the Shift + 2 combination.. I find that it maps to

[image]

Removing that mapping will change it to Shift+Super+Home, which allows me to use Shift+2 to display @ once again.

Comment: As you already have my green backgrounded answer, I can recommend to drop GNOME sHell and continue with green functional DE (you know the name). It may be faster than finding the reasons of GNOME misfunction.

Comment: Thanks, for those who finds this answer.. N0bert is talking about the Ubuntu Mate Desktop Environment.

Comment: What is your current desktop environment? If it is GNOME, then please add screenshot of `gnome-control-center keyboard` with search for `Shift` (like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUFhe.png)) to the question.

Comment: My DE was the standard GNOME. I added the screenshot and it in doing so found a way to resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the keyboard shortcuts in GNOME Control Center (Keyboard tab):

1. Open it from dash (or with `gnome-control-center keyboard`)
2. Compare your settings with default settings below:

   [image: keyboard shortcuts]

   and locate or change the problematic items.